# Are there performance benefits when upgrading SQL2000 to SQL2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, performance, sql-server-2000, migration

I've had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140733/why-should-i-upgrade-from-sql2000-to-sql2005) question but there are no responses regarding performance.

Are there any performance benefits from doing a simple upgrade from SQL2000 to SQL2005?

I am thinking a line of business OLTP datbase.
I am not using OLAP or FTI.

Comment: Adding this as a comment as not really a complete answer: if you tell a little more about whether you do OLTP, OLAP, full-text indexing you might get better answers.

One example of improvement is that the performance of LIKE queries (that don't beging with '%') has improved because LIKE now uses indexes...

Comment: interesting on the LIKE queiries.

Answer (score 2):

We found yes.

The query optimiser is updated and better.
We found a lot of query plans were different with absolutely no other changes.

Even our end users commented on the speed improvement and general responsiveness. I have the email to prove it :-D

At the same time, we re-wrote a very few stored procs because they were worse. However, the same tweaks also improved response on SQL 2000 and was simply poor code/ideas.

Comment: It was 2 years ago... Our metrics will probably be useless anyway because every app is different. We're very satisfied with the upgrade for the new features, not just performance.

Comment: I'll second gbn on this - we did this upgrade a while back and got a very nice performance boost.

Answer (score 0):

Not in my experience.

If you want to improve your database performance, I tend to throw more hardware at it in the form of **more RAM** and **faster disks**.

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found much on this but here is a load of marketing stuff that essentially says SQL2005 is a good thing:

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/white-papers.aspx#gen

and in this white paper ["Why upgrade to SQLSERVER2005"(.doc)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/4/7/a47b7b0e-976d-4f49-b15d-f02ade638ebe/SQLServer2005_WhyUpgrade.doc)

it states

> **Faster Response Times for End Users**
>
> Database query response times have
>   improved 70−80 percent for many
>   applications converted from SQL Server
>   2000 to SQL Server 2005. Quicker
>   response times to queries help
>   business users react faster and enable
>   the database to be used for real-time
>   decision making. Queries that might
>   have previously taken several hours
>   can now be completed in a matter of
>   minutes. This provides a whole new
>   level of functionality for end-users
>   because analysis can be done on an ad
>   hoc basis rather than exclusively in
>   predefined reports. Companies can use
>   this new accessibility to information
>   to dynamically monitor processes.

Answer (score 0):

On the flip side to benefits there seem to be few problems when upgrading.

[Why would upgrading from SQL Server 2000 to 2005 result in slower queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489137/why-would-upgrading-from-sql-server-2000-to-2005-result-in-slower-queries)

http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=4&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eggheadcafe.com%2Fforumarchives%2FSQLServersetup%2FFeb2006%2Fpost26068566.asp&ei=76XNSpHWJ5bWmQPDwdSMAw&usg=AFQjCNGY15FipRCEzPq2OVcomXqys08hTA&sig2=UN5mcW6T7es0D_UUCcuizQ